# Why is 2 not > 0 ?? It is instead <= 0, but not < 0, nor == 0

Tags: c++, math, compare, c++17

I was messing around a bit in C++ when I came across an issue that made absolutely no sense to me. For some reason with a variable equal to 2, 2 > 0 returns false, but 2 <= 0 and 2 >= 0 return true, while also somehow 2 < 0 and 2 == 0 return false. However, if I use just a static 2, everything works as intended.

Here's the entire code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long long f (long long n)
{
    while (n > 0);
    {
        n /= 10;
    }
    cout << n << ": " << endl;
    cout << n << " > 0  =  " << (n > 0) << endl;
    cout << n << " < 0  =  " << (n < 0) << endl;
    cout << n << " >= 0  =  " << (n >= 0) << endl;
    cout << n << " <= 0  =  " << (n <= 0) << endl;
    cout << 2 << ": " << endl;
    cout << 2 << " > 0  =  " << (2 > 0) << endl;
    cout << 2 << " < 0  =  " << (2 < 0) << endl;
    cout << 2 << " >= 0  =  " << (2 >= 0) << endl;
    cout << 2 << " <= 0  =  " << (2 <= 0) << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    long long n = 27;
    f(n);
}
```

This returns:

```
2: 
2 > 0  =  0
2 < 0  =  0
2 >= 0  =  1
2 <= 0  =  1
2: 
2 > 0  =  1
2 < 0  =  0
2 >= 0  =  1
2 <= 0  =  0
```

Comment: Try printing the actual value of `n`. It should be `0`. And it should be `0` because your loop will divide `27 / 10` which is `2`, then it will divide `2 / 10` which is `0`.

Comment: But I am printing it, I print it right after the while loop in the line
" cout << n << ": " << endl; "
and it returns
" 2: "

Comment: `while (n > 0);` looks broken to me...

Comment: `warning: this 'while' clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]` -- did you really mean that semicolon after the `while`?

Comment: Your loop is `while(n > 0);` with a semi colon at the end. It is an infinite loop. In C++ an infinite loop with no side effects is Undefined Behavior and your program can do anything.

Comment: I could've sworn I deleted that semicolon, sorry for such a dumb mistake, been here for like an hour completely unable to see the issue. Thank you all very much.

Comment: @tatoyoda600 Missing or extra semicolon are extremely common. This won't be the last. I suggest compiling with flags `-Wall -Wextra` to get warnings on these kinds of mistakes.

Comment: @Stef: Absolutely. With compilers getting more and more aggressive it's even more important to check and clear warnings.

Comment: Voting to reopen - I'd appreciate an answer on this from an expert in compiler design. This is deeper than a simple typo.

Comment: This has nothing to do with compiler optimization. Even if you removed the semi-colon, you are still dividing by 10 until `n` is zero. Perhaps this is closer to what you were trying to do: `while (n >= 10) { n /= 10; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler assumes that `n` is a zero when evaluating the conditionals.

It's allowed to do that since `while (n > 0);` is undefined for positive `n`, and a compiler is allowed to assume there is no undefined behaviour.

This is plausible since conditionals can cause branch prediction failures whereas outputting `n` (which is 2 once you've taken the integer division by 10) does not. A lot of compiler optimisation these days is centred around not dumping the pipeline.

With something like this, check the generated assembly.

With a less aggressively optimising compiler, you would probably end up with an infinite loop with no output.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on why it did what it did, never would have thought that that is what it was doing.

Answer (score 1):

Dumb mistake, left the semicolon after the while(n > 0) and seems that caused some weird side effects.